# Position of hamze for Farsi/Persian with ArabTeX

Tags: persian, arabtex

In the following document I want the *hamze* (*hamza*, written with `'` in ArabTeX) to be above in all the examples, and not on the side as it is in the second group. How can I achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\setfarsi

\begin{document}
Good: \RL{' Bi'-}

Not good: \RL{w' Y'}

\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]

The result is actually the same without `\setfarsi`. I included it because I suspect that the positioning is correct for Arabic, but not for Farsi, so it could be expected to have been changed by `\setfarsi`.

Big caveat though: I don't know Arabic *or* Farsi. (I'm asking for someone else.)

**Addendum:** Later the person with the question added that the behaviour she wanted was what she learned in school, but she has since seen that both versions are used. So I take back the part about not being correct.

Answer (score 1):

some remarks are here

```
\documentclass{article}
\addtolength\textwidth{1.8in}
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-.8in}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\setfarsi

\begin{document}
Good: \RL{' Bi'-}

this is good: \RL{w'} in \textbf{the end of word} example: \RL{ysw'}
but there this is  also \RL{Amru'} and \RL{tnbu'}


this is good: \RL{y'} in \textbf{the end of word}  example: \RL{^sy'}

this is not good \RL{Y'} but there is \RL{Amru|i'}

there is no hamza with waw and ya in the beginning of word

the 3 rd forme is \RL{lu'lu'} \RL{mu'mn}, \RL{Albi'r} \RL{mi'dnT} \RL{ra'iys}

\end{document}
```

for arabic hamza